# Swift reload data collectionview when changing segmentation control

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview and I am showing 2 image per cell and in header I have segmentation control.
When the first load everything is ok I can see two images every cell but when I change the segmentation I can see one image in cell and first one is bigger than others.

What is my wrong and what is missing in my code? I want to see two image in cell and all images should be same size

My codes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "cell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.delegate = self

    addSegmentationControl()
}

func addSegmentationControl(){

    let items = [first, second]
    segmentedController = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TopMediasViewController.segmentedControlActionChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    navigationItem.titleView = segmentedController
}

@objc func segmentedControlActionChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    //self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)

}

 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = 0

    switch(segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            returnValue = firstData.count
            break
        case 1:
            returnValue = secondData.count
            break
        default:
            break
    }

    return returnValue
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TopMediasCollectionViewCell

    switch(segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:

            medias = self.firstData
            break
        case 1:

            medias = self.secondData
            break
        default:
            break
    }

    let media = medias[indexPath.row]

    let imageUrl = media.mediaImageUrl

    AF.request(imageUrl).responseImage { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let image):
            cell.imgView.image = image
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let noOfCellsInRow = 2

    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))

    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))

    return CGSize(width: size, height: (size / 4 * 3))

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making estimated size for your collection you to None.

[image]